# prevent vue-router to open same path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, navigation, vue-router

can you give me some feedback about my solution?

I want to prevent vue router to open a site the user sees already.

The problem was: the user had open a site with a double id as paramters like this: `path: '/detail/:idType/:itemId` After a click on the same tab again the last id `/:itemId` was removed in the url and the user sees a different view, which I want to prevent.

My current solution is adding a [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards):

```js
// router.js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.name === from.name) return
    else next()
})
```

Is it okay to `return` if the names matches?
Do I use the correct router method?

thanks!

---

### Edit for Praveen

```
// router.js
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/new',
            name: 'New',
            component: () => import('../layout/New'),
            props: {
                mode: 'create'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/edit/:uuid',
            name: 'Edit',
            component: () => import('../layout/New'),
            props: {
                mode: 'edit'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/detail/:idType/:itemId/:uuidId?',
            name: 'Detail',
            component: () => import('../layout/Detail'),
            props: true,
        }
    ],
    mode: 'hash',
    linkActiveClass: 'active'
})
```

```
// tab navigation
<b-link
  :to="{ name: ['Edit', 'Detail'].indexOf($route.name) !== -1 ? $route.name : 'New'}"
  class="btn btn-site-nav"
  type="button" 
  v-text="'Booking'" 
/>
```

Comment: While the answer by @tao might work for you I wanna know what your router configuration looks like for the same. It may be that you aren't nesting your router views properly.

Comment: I have added the simplified configuration. What do you think about it? I don't use nested routes at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To abort a navigation, call `next(false)` (in your case: `if (to.name === from.name) next(false)`)

To allow it to pass (to its target), call `next` with `undefined`: `next()` (or `next(undefined)` - if you want to write more explicit code)

And to redirect it, call `next` with an object containing either `name` or `path` (i.e: `next({ name: 'Login' })`)